# XCode open file at error line for custom build script

Tags: xcode4

I Apologize if this question has already been asked. i can't seem to find it anywhere if it has.

I have a custom build script use to syntax check some php files and upload them to a server, and this is executed as a part of the build process. since this script is used to parse inline php statements (embedded in objective c blocks using macros) it's fairly critical this script happens on each build. the actual execution is working fine, i'd just also like to be able to open a particular file when there is an error, and locate the cursor in the approximate location.

i have found that since xcode is configured on my system to open .php files by default (not sure if that's the norm or if i did it manually at some point), using

```
open filename.php
```

in a shell script opens the file.

i'd like to be able to specify the line number too.

eg something along the lines of

```
open filename.php --args --jump-to-line 1234
```

(--args is a switch for "open" meaning pass the arguments on to Xcode)

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `xed` command. Only works for Xcode 3 though, not other editors. For Xcode 4, try [this](https://gist.github.com/dunkelstern/2250729)

See [`man xed`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xed.1.html)

Comment: `xed -l <linenum> <file>` works for Xcode 8.2.1 at least. It opens the file and selects the line, but won't actually scroll to the line until you hit a cursor key. Or you can hit Ctrl-L to centre the line in the window (i.e. the key bound to "Center Selection in Visible Area")